# Worklight - How to check for Internet connectivity when previewing the Common web resources?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, internet-connection

I'm trying to check in my Worklight app whether  the device has an Internet connection.

[In the documentation for WL.Device.getNetworkInfo](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_mobile_network_details.html) it is said that this API method only supports Android and iOS.

So my question is, how do I check for Internet connection if I preview the Common web resources and not the Android or iOS environment of my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web browsers do not provide any APIs to check things like your IP address, network type etc. Mobile devices do provide this functionality. Therefore it will work on mobile device and will not work on a web browser.

What you can do on a web browser is

1. Make explicit request and see whether it succeeds/fails
2. Listen to worklight connected/disconnected events - slide 8 of http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_04_Working_offline.pdf